# Detect my parameter in my stored procedure contains only 6 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I detect my `@AE_LedgerAC` parameter in my store procedure contains only 6 characters? if it contains only 6 characters, I want to add in front the details contain on this table `BIN.BranchId`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccountEntries]

    @AE_LedgerAC varchar(21)=null,
    @AE_Transaction_Ref varchar(50)=null,
    @AE_Detail nvarchar(50)=null,
AS
    DECLARE @NEW_LedgerAC varchar(21) = null

    IF(LEN(@AE_LedgerAC) = 6)
    BEGIN
        @NEW_LedgerAC = SELECT TOP 1 BIN.BranchId FROM BIN + @AE_LedgerAC
    ELSE
        @NEW_LedgerAC = @AE_LedgerAC

    INSERT INTO [AccountEntries](LedgerAC, Transaction_Ref, Detail)
    VALUES (@AE_LedgerAC, @AE_Transaction_Ref, @AE_Detail)
```

Comment: like for example? *..add in front the details contain on this table BIN.BranchId*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use LEN ( string_expression )

```
IF(LEN(@AE_LedgerAC) = 6)
BEGIN

...
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is MSSQL, check out the following links from Microsoft's MSDN:

[LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)

[IF/ELSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)

[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[SET @local_variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx)